# updating a column value with '&' giving xml parser error in the trigger

Tags: sql, xml, triggers

I am updatinga column value/below is the query

```
update Test set reference='Payment block & in SAP removed'
where id=2065.
```

And in the trigger which executes after update I am building an xml.query is

```
set @xmlstring='<Changes>'

if(isnull(@oldReference,'')<>isnull(@newReference,''))
            begin
            set @IsChanged=1
            set @xmlstring=@xmlstring+'<Fields Name="' + @Reference + '" OldValue="' + cast(isnull(@oldReference,'') as nvarchar) + '" NewValue="' + cast(isnull(@newReference,'') as nvarchar) + '" />'
            end

set @xmlstring=@xmlstring + '</Changes>'
```

But the trigger is giving xml parsing exception . Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The '&' characters needs to be encoded in XML as '`&amp;`'.